# How do I share functionality between my expressjs routes?

Tags: node.js, express

Suppose I have two routes in my expresjss project: users.js and profiles.js.

users.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var extra = something_nice();
  res.json( { three: 'four', extra: extra } );
});

module.exports = router;
```

profiles.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET profiles listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var extra = something_nice();
  res.json( { one: 'two', extra: extra } );
});

module.exports = router;
```

Notice how I have something_nice() method there, which ideally I would define in a 'super class' if this were regular OOP like rails controllers.

How do I go about this with node + expressjs? My assumption was I should create a new module, and require it here, but is this the best practice?

Comment: If `something_nice()` is only used in one routes file, there's no need to put it in its own module.  If you want to share it across multiple routes files, then put it in its own module, export and then you can import it anywhere you want to use it.  It's just like sharing any other functionality in node.js.  No different for routes.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yup, I understand the concept. But having to export them and require them everywhere feels like I'm copying myself. I.e. handling user authorization the same way across routes, and having to require('session_auth') on every single one of them feels weird.

Comment: Well, maybe you're spreading things out across too many files if you're reimporting the same thing dozens of times.  Or, maybe you just haven't gotten used to the modularity in node.js and start to feel the benefits of it all.  Yes, there is some extra, oft-repeated boilerplate at the top of many modules to import the things you need, but the benefits down the road are enormous from good modularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that accepts the `router` instance as an argument and can implement your common logic inside that function. Javascript uses composition instead of inheritance.

```
module.exports=function (router){

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var extra = something_nice();
  res.json( { one: 'two', extra: extra } );
});

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You solve it in the same way. Using a class:

```js
class SomethingCool {
  somethingNice() {
    return 'cool!';  
  }
}

module.exports = SomethingCool;
```

In your route:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var SomethingCool = require('./something-cool.class');

const something = new SomethingCool();

/* GET profiles listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var extra = something.somethingNice();
  res.json( { one: 'two', extra: extra } );
});

module.exports = router;
```

Same principles should apply regardless of language (as long as they have support for classes, or class-like objects).

Also you don't even need a class here:

```js
function somethingNice() {
  // some logic
}

// inside file1
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const extra = somethingNice();
  res.json({ one: 'two', extra });
});
```

You can reuse functions where you like/need, just ensure they're exported using module.exports (if using in a different file/module).

Have a read over this when you have time:

- https://dev.to/santypk4/bulletproof-node-js-project-architecture-4epf

It may be able to answer some of the questions you later have about design, structure and reusing logic in different areas.

EDIT: an explanation on how middleware can help in certain situations.

- https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

```js
function isUserAdmin(user) {
  // some logic for determining
}


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (isUserAdmin(req.user)) {
    req.role = 'Admin';
  }  

  next();
});
```

This is a simplified example, in reality you'd also need to add the `req.user`.

The thing to understand here, is your ability to use middleware to reuse functionality.

However, if you wanted something a little more specific to the route, then I'd opt to use a class (following the Service pattern from other reference link).

Another (more common) example, consider a logger, it outputs which endpoint was requested and with what method:

```js
// file: service/logger.service.js
class LoggerService {
  log(message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
}
module.exports = MyLogger;

// file: middleware/logger.middleware.js
const logger = new MyLogger();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const path = req.path;
  const method = req.method;

  logger.log(`${path} ${method}`);

  return next();
});
```

This way, your route never needs to know about the logger, or what function it has, you can plug an unlimited amount of additional functionality this way.

Although it's more suited for generic tasks, like checking a user has authenticated (for example), or is authorized, but it's certainly not limited to only that type of use.

If you really want a super class, then use a singleton:

```js
class SuperClass {
  constructor() {
    this.someOtherClass = new UserClass();
    this.someSecondClass = new ProjectClass();
  }

  doSuperWork() {

  }
}

module.exports = new SuperClass();
```

I'll say though, it may not be the best solution (super classes in general).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the awesome post. So in the end, it means I will eventually have to `var SomethingCool = require('./something-cool.class');` for every routes file I want the feature added, right? No way to 'subclass' and have it be automatically there. If I need to import 4, 5 modules, I'll end up with 5 extra lines for each route, etc?

Comment: @MarceloRibeiro that would depend on the level of abstraction you're looking to add, and also on the function of `extra`, could you provide a little more detail of what functionality would be shared between your routes?

Comment: i.e. user authorization based on the user's role (admin, client, etc)

Comment: In that case, middleware may be the option to use, you create a middleware function that's called before the route handler. I'll add some references to my original answer.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. Although I see a lot of value in it, what I was really looking for was accomplished by the answer from @akin above. That way I can add functionality to my router for a subset of my routes (or all of them if I want to), add extra requires within my baseRouter function, and deal with specifics within each route. Basically this: `var router = baseRouter(express.Router());` and have baseRouter handle the router, add common routes, objects or features, imports, etc.

Comment: @MarceloRibeiro that's my bad, I misunderstood you in that case, however I'm glad there's still value there for you, I'll keep the answer posted. I'm glad you got the answer you were looking for, all the best!